# Importing without changing primary address

Tags: import, addresses

Is there a way to tell CiviCRM not to set newly-imported addresses as primary addresses?

For example, let's say I have a database where everyone has nicely-curated "Home" addresses. I make a new location type "Voter" to import voter file addresses. The import process will make "Voter" the primary, but I want "Home" to remain primary.

The only way I know of is to backup the civicrm_address table and revert them using SQL, but it would be nice to skip that step.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a way to handle this through the User Interface. I added a function into a custom extension, which seems to solve the issue:

```
function myext_civicrm_pre($op, $objectName, $objectId, &$params) {
  if ($objectName == 'Address' && ($op == 'create' || $op == 'edit')) {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/civicrm/import/contact') {
      unset($params['is_primary']);
    }
  }
}
```